# Parse issue : Module "module name" not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoapods

So, I'm trying to build and run a project so I can simulate an iOS app with Xcode(Version 11.3.1 (11C505))on my Mac.

- I clone the repository, check into the branch I'm supposed to,
- install submodules (git submodule update --init --recursive),
- pod install (I made sure to install CocoaPods with sudo gem install
  cocoapods before)
- open project.xcworkspace

When I try to build or build and run the build fails and the error I get is as the title reads. This is exactly what my coworkers apparently are doing / did to run the app with the simulator but I'm the only one getting that error.

I'm using a Mac mini (Late 2014) with Catalina 10.15.4 (19E266). When it comes to Xcode, I already mention the version and I literally just downloaded it, installed it and tried to run the app... not like I've been messing with settings or anything.
Does anyone know if there's something I can do ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the module name to your podfile?

Comment: Well, yes, I believe it is there. I mean, the module it's not finding it's called AgoraRtcEnginekIT and In the podfile I can see this pod added: - pod AgoraRtcEngine_iOS - which I believe should include the one my Xcode can't find ? The thing is, this is not my code, I downloaded it and follow instructions as told, so do other people but I'm the only one getting that parsing issue.

Comment: There are lots of similar questions with all sorts if answers on SO. I would start there.